# FCM: where best to retrieve data displayed in the notification?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app where I have set up some triggers using Firebase Functions.  Those triggers will send push notifications to a set of users when they go off.  The notification will display some information based on the trigger that could involve getting data from one or more collections based on ids.

I now see two options:

1. I could retrieve the data that will be displayed in the notifications on the server side in the trigger function and send it in the notification data payload, or
2. I could just send the ids through the notification data payload and do the retrieval of the displayed data on the client side in onMessageReceived() before building the notification that is ultimately displayed

Is one option better than another?  What considerations should I take into account for either option?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the first option makes more sense, since the server side function is perfectly capable of performing the complete operation all by itself, and would probably be more performatic with it.

Not to mention that, if your are using Firestore for example, you would only make one read per notification, instead of two with the second option.

Another final point to be considered that advocates for the first option is that the network may fail in the middle of your operation, and the notification would either be showned incomplete, or you would have to treat any errors it might generate on the client side, if you do it all on the server side, you can simply not send a "error notification" to your users and retry the operation.

Comment: Thanks, @ralemos.  That all makes sense.